# XCode Swift iOS 8 - Lighting Torch in Background

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, background, flashlight

Is there a way to stay the LED on, even when the app is in the background?

The code for the torch works fine but only in the foreground.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Torch in background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25485556/torch-in-background)

Comment: i thought something changed since 6 months ago

Comment: Unlikely. You could check the API diffs, but the rules for what apps can do in the background are quite well established.